# How do I loop through posted json array

Tags: json, scala, playframework

The following JSON Array is posted in to my scala app:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 501,
    "Name": "effectiveDate",
    "Value": "14:15:33 GMT"
  },
  {
    "Id": 829,
    "Name": "effectiveData",
    "Value": "15:10:44 GMT",    

  }
]
```

Using the following, I can access the posted data:

```
val req = if (request.body != null) request.body else null 
   println(req)
```

However, I need to loop through it and work on each object individual.

I have tried req.foreach {whatever} but Scala Playframework didn't like it.

So, how can I do this?
I'm thinking that I'd need something like pythons

```py
for item in array:
    print(item)
```

or PHPs

```php
foreach ($array as $item) {
    echo $item
}
```

UPDATE:
I added `println(ClassTag(req.getClass))` 
to the file. The response is : `play.api.libs.json.JsArray` .

I checked, `import play.api.libs.json.JsArray` is definitely at the top of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it.
I put this in the class declaration

```
  object Message {
    implicit val jsonFormat: Format[Message] = Json.format[Message]
  }
```

Then this in the handler

```
val req = if (request.body != null) request.body else null 
    val messages = (req).as[Seq[Message]]

    messages.foreach{
      // do what you want
      println(_)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Json library:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val req = if (request.body != null) request.body else null 
val jsonReq: JsValue = Json.parse(req)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that has give me different errors: `: overloaded method value parse with alternatives:
[error]   (input: Array[Byte])play.api.libs.json.JsValue <and>
[error]   (input: java.io.InputStream)play.api.libs.json.JsValue <and>
[error]   (input: String)play.api.libs.json.JsValue
[error]  cannot be applied to (play.api.libs.json.JsValue)
[error]     val jsonReq: JsValue = Json.parse(req)
[error]                                 ^
[error] one error found
[error] (accounts/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
request.body.validate[RefData] //create a case class RefData
```

or convert to string first

```
val req = if (request.body != null) request.body.toString() else null 
val jsonReq: JsValue = Json.parse(req)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a `case` class to map the JSON, you can iterate over the array with the following:

```
Option(request.body).fold[JsValue](JsNull)(Json.parse) match {
  case arr: JsArray => arr.value.foreach(elem => println(s"Element: $elem"))
  case _ => println(s"unexpected JSON: ${request.body}")
}
```

Wrapping `request.body` in Option deals with `null` checking for you and sets you up for the match statement.

Answer (score 0):

By using body-parser you can handle the body as an Option with `asJson.map`, convert it to an Array with `validate.map` and then iterating over it.

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue

Action { request: Request[AnyContent] =>
  request.body.asJson.map {
    _.validate[Array[JsValue]].map {
      _.foreach(println)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: apparently `value asJson is not a member of play.api.libs.json.JsValue
[error]     request.body.asJson.map {`

Comment: I will add some more details in the example code for better copy-paste ;)

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of hack and slash options in the answers, but none of them is good idea. Take a look at [Body Parsers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaBodyParsers) and [Json API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaJson).

Here is how I would do the job

```
  import play.api.libs.json._

  case class VO(Id: Long, Name: String, Value: String)

  implicit val format = Json.format[VO]

  def hello = Action(parse.json[List[VO]]) { req =>
    val listVO: List[VO] = req.body
    ???
  }
```

By using the play body parsers, you tell the framework what is the expect request body type. Then you will get validation for free. If there is any kind of error (e.g. property is missing or has a wrong type) the framework will return BAD REQUEST to the client with message describing the problem.

Using JsObject directly is not a good idea. This low level API is not very convenient. Most notably, you will have to handle a lot of error cases and use strings to access properties, and thus loose type safety.